# Ruby gem for consuming Webservices wsdl with xsd:import

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, savon

We need to consume a webservices which got a WSDL that uses xsd:import for Data Types definitions.
savon gem doesn't support as it uses wasabi.
We are using Ruby 1.9.2 
Could you please suggest me some gems.

Regards
Surendran

Comment: Surendran, I'm not 100% on this, but try soap4r.  I'll test later in the day and let you know for sure if you haven't had a chance before then.

Comment: @ValAkkapeddi : Do you mean the gem from http://rubygems.org/gems/soap4r ?

Comment: That's the one - I likely won't be able to test it until tonight, but please see if it does the job for you.

Comment: Unfortunately soap4r no longer appears to be maintained. I've used it with some success in the past. The best guidance I can provide is to look at ruby-toolbox https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/soap Unfortunately, most of those don't appear to be maintained either, likely because everyone in the ruby community justifiably hates soap.

Comment: how about using a custom parser with [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)?

Comment: or [handsoap](https://github.com/unwire/handsoap)

Comment: unfortunately, there is no good wsdl parser in ruby land. have you thought about using jruby? the java guys have some great soap libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem any Gem out there which does what you want. My proposal for this situation:

1. use SoapUI to examine the Web Service
2. write your client using Savon http://savonrb.com

I've done this several times, there are a lot of people here who can help you with that approach.